# Adding numbers to a piped command line command

Tags: command-line

I've got a command that produces some data...

```
$./thing  
some
random
data
```

I'd like to be able to execute

```
$./thing | somecoolcommand
```

and get

```
1 some
2 random 
3 data
```

can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wanted the 'nl' command...